# PHP/Laravel - Short(er)hand if with only true

Tags: php, laravel

PHP 7+
Is it possible to write a shorthand boolean check with only a true action

original:

```
if ($this->debug) Log::debug('batch '. $this->count);
```

ie, something like:

```
$this->debug ? Log::debug('batch '. $this->count);
```

Comment: Can I ask why?!  The original `if()` statement is clear and obvious, the shorthand (IMHO) is unclear and pointless (as shown in the example)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you're on a right path, you just need an else clause, if your condition fails:

```
$this->debug ? Log::debug('batch '. $this->count) : 'else' ;
```

Comment: Thanks - this shows me why it wasnt working - so I've accepted it as the answer - though I will go ahead with the standard 'if' statement then :)

Comment: Sure, as @N69S, there's no need to use ternary operators here. It's more convenient to use them while assigning a variables, since it's easier to read.

Comment: Comes to something when the shorthand version is actually longer than the original code.

Answer (score 1):

The shorthand version if useful when you want to assign a variable since it **returns a value** depending on the condition.

In your case, you dont need the result, you just want the code to be executed.

So in reality, there are no alternative to

```php
if ($this->debug)
    Log::debug('batch '. $this->count);
```